# Is there a splitting rule for the restriction of a $GL(23, \mathbb{Q})$-representation to $O(23, \mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I am interested in a $23$-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $V$ which I am viewing as a GL$_{23}(\mathbb{Q})$ representation. Schur functors can be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, so we get representations $\Gamma_\lambda=\mathbb{S}_\lambda V$ corresponding to partitions $\lambda$ (following the notation in Fulton and Harris *Representation Theory: A First Course*). There is also a quadratic form $q$ on $V$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so we similarly get representations $\Gamma_\lambda$ of O$(q)$.

If I was working over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}$, Fulton and Harris Equation 25.37 gives a formula for restricting these GL$_{23}(\mathbb{C})$-representations $\Gamma_\lambda$ to O$_{23}(\mathbb{C})$:
$$\mathrm{Res}^{GL_{23}(\mathbb{C})}_{O_{23}(\mathbb{C})} (\Gamma_\lambda) = \bigoplus N_{\lambda\bar{\lambda}} \Gamma_{\bar{\lambda}},$$
where $N_{\lambda\bar{\lambda}}=\sum_{\delta} N_{\delta\bar{\lambda}\lambda}$, a sum of Littlewood-Richardson coefficients.

I am wondering, does this same formula hold when everything is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, as above? Any references for this would be extremely helpful.